# Playing subtitles - and only subtitles - on Android

Tags: accessibility

I've decided to embark on learning Spanish.  Last time I learned a foreign language, I was in a foreign country watching a lot of American TV subtitled in the local language.  Seeing the translation of things said on the show was very helpful.

I'd like to watch my Netflix movies (and possibly other sources as well, like Amazon streaming) with Spanish subtitles, but Netflix generally does not support them.

There are a large number of free, independently-made subtitle archives out there; it would be an easy task to download the subtitles for a movie or TV show I'm about to watch.

I'd like to sit in my TV room and watch movies or TV shows on my TV, while the subtitles are displayed on my phone.  While there are a few video players out there that support external subtitles, I have been unable to find a way to do subtitle-only viewing. Is there an app or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more searching, I found [SubtitlePlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.vinczeg.subtitleplayer) in the Google Play Store.

It seems to work adequately for what I need, but because its name is two words jammed together, doesn't show up when you search for "Subtitle" in the market.

Also, the page says it needs 'Unicode' subtitles; after a few tries, I got it to work correctly with UTF-8 encoding, without a BOM.

Comment: That's a nice find.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but one thing that comes on the top of my mind is to use a video that has nothing but a black background play on your mobile. You can then add subtitles to it and may be increase the subtitle size, change the position etc to suit you. Hope this helps :)